# Cutting an object in half and deforming it

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can I cut an irregular shape object in half **(the first image)** and use the SimpleDefrom Modifier to create an animated bend like the animation below (**the second animated image**)?

I have an irregular shape object below:

**Please note the images below are just examples:**

[image]

I would like to be able to control the bend like the animated cylinder below.

Note: I used the cylinder as an example because I knew how to make it look like it was cut in "half" and then bent back to a cylinder.

[image: Bend image]

Comment: you mean you want it to be flat at the beginning and then be able to bend it in order to recreate its round shape?

Comment: Not necessarily flat, but having it as an object cut in half that forms back into the original object.  I used the cylinder as an example.  The original object is the cylinder and it's cut in half.  Using the Simple Deform bends the cut piece back to the original cylinder shape.

Comment: but your object looks like a sphere, so it would mean that it folds in 2 axis?

Comment: I updated the question.  Honestly I don't know how many axis it would take hence the question.

Comment: is your original object a pre-existing spherical object that you need to turn flat or is it (or can it be) flat (or almost flat) that you need to turn spherical? it will be easier to start with a flat as you just need to give it 2 Simple Deform modifier

Comment: It's a pre-existing "irregular spherical shape"  object.